# Problem with bounds array shape in scipy.optimize constrained methods

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, scipy-optimize

Followup to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912426/how-to-organize-list-of-list-of-lists-to-be-compatible-with-scipy-optimize-fmin) now I have a problem with the shape of the bounds array in the [constrained bfgs method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html#scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b).

My code is the following:

```
nr      = 5
lag     = 1


guess       =numpy.array([[[ random.uniform(-1.0,1.0) for k in range(nr)] for l in range(lag)],
                          [[ random.uniform( 0.0,1.0) for k in range(nr)] for l in range(lag)],
                          [[ random.uniform(-1.0,1.0) for k in range(nr)] for l in range(lag)]])

bounds      =numpy.array([[[ [-1.0,1.0] for k in range(nr)] for l in range(lag)],
                          [[ [ 0.0,1.0] for k in range(nr)] for l in range(lag)],
                          [[ [-1.0,1.0] for k in range(nr)] for l in range(lag)]])

result      =   optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b( myfunc,guess.flatten(),bounds=bounds.reshape(15,2) )
```

As you can see I start out with a (3,1,5) shaped list of lists, which is my preferred format with which I work inside the `myfunc()` because it's easy to parse with nested for loops.Then this list gets crunched into a (15,) shaped numpy array to satisfy the `x0` parameter's format needs, but don't worry because the `X` value inside the `myfunc()` is then transformed back into my (3,1,5) format via `X=X.reshape(origshape)` where the `origshape` global variable will save the original format. It may seem inefficient and a useless back and forth but I couldn't find a way to do it easier.

Now this works with every `fmin_` function so far except with bounds like `fmin_l_bfgs_b`, I couldn't figure out what shape the bounded values need to be in. The documentation says:

> "(min, max) pairs for each element in x, defining the bounds on that parameter."

So I thought this means 1 pair for each element, so a (15,2) shape in my situation, but when I use the code above, it gives me the following error:

`TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

So I guess I got the shape wrong. Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result      =   optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b( myfunc,guess.flatten(),bounds=bounds.reshape(15,2),approx_grad=True )
```

It seems like it doesn't work without setting the `approx_grad` variable to True. Otherwise I guess you need to specify the fprime function.

Either way the function seems to be depreciated and using the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function is better.